# Jquery / Javascript plugin for in-browser data analysis and charting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone suggest an existing Javascript / JQuery based Analytics plugin? I spent some time searching but cannot find a quick one.

It may works like getting feed with data from external and providing basic charts to web containing element, like distribution, average, correlation of 2 data arrays, etc. Thx.

Comment: [d3.js](http://d3js.org/)? And btw, I don't think this question is suitable for SO.

Comment: Agree. I think I'll close it soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for something lightweight, you might want to check out [Chartist JS](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/). It doesn't have all of the bells and whistles of some other plugins, but it's quick to get up and running. There are even wrappers for integration with libraries/frameworks like Angular & WordPress.

For something more robust, check out Highcharts or D3, or something built on top of D3 like [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/).